# In Sinatra how do I specify folders for other template engines?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a small app with a folder structure like so

```
MyApp
  +--public
    +--javascripts
    +--stylesheets
  +--specs
  +--views
```

The sinatra document specifies to use the find_templates function of helpers to be able to change he lookup paths for the diferent engines.

```
set :views, :coffee => 'public/javascripts', :sass => 'public/stylesheets', :default => 'views'

helpers do
  def find_template(views, name, engine, &block)
    _, folder = views.detect { |k,v| engine == Tilt[k] }
    folder ||= views[:default]
    super(folder, name, engine, &block)
  end
end
```

is this the only way to change the default lookup path from the views folder for coffeescript and sass?

Answer (score 0):

`public` should not contain any views, it should contain static files. If they are static files, just serve them as static files with your web server, no need to get Sinatra, let alone any template engines, involved. Serve them with `static_file` if you have a good reason to do so (access restrictions, user configuration dependent file picking, etc.)

Aside from that I don't know of any way that Tilt/Sinatra support different template directories for different template engines. You can however specify a subdirectory as part of the template name as `scss :'scss/style'` for example. These would then be subdirectories of the `views` directory, which by the way you can change `set :views` as per the Sinatra documentation.

Comment: quite a long time since I've seen this lol,  But thank you for answering.  I guess at the time my logic was since I will be requesting coffescript and sass files as js and css files, why would they be views and not public files.  I use views for just the haml files.